# Apache's StringUtils.isBlank(str) vs. Guava's Strings.isNullOrEmpty(str): Should you routinely check for whitespace?

Tags: java, string, apache-commons, guava

Is there any advantage in using

```
StringUtils.isBlank(str)
```

from Apache commons-lang.

vs

```
Strings.isNullOrEmpty(String string)
```

from Google Guava?

I want to replace hundreds of cases of they following usage in a Java project:

```
if(str == null || str.isEmpty())
```

Guava's [isNullOrEmpty](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Strings.html#isNullOrEmpty-java.lang.String-) seems to be a direct replacement for the usage above in my project.

But more people seem to use Apache's [isBlank](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.6/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isBlank-java.lang.CharSequence-) method based on my reading of S.O. questions.

The only difference seems to be that `StringUtils.isBlank(str)` **also checks for whitespace** in addition to checking whether the string is null or empty.

**Normally is it a good idea to check a String for whitespace or could that produce a different result in your code than Guava's simpler check?**

Comment: Of course it can produce a different result. Both methods do not perform the same thing.

Comment: Hey don't forget to add springs StringUtils to the bunch: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/util/StringUtils.html

Comment: See also: https://github.com/google/guava/issues/352

Answer (score 17):

If you want to use Guava to replicate the isBlank behaviour, I would use the following method instead:

`Strings.nullToEmpty(str).trim().isEmpty()`

Answer (score 8):

When you have to accept input from human beings, you should be forgiving and strip leading and trailing whitespace from whatever text they type, if it makes sense in the particular application.

That said, using `isBlank` is only halfbaked. You also need to `trim` the strings before processing them further. So I suggest to use `s = trim(s);` before checking with `isNullOrEmpty`.

Comment: That’s why I wrote `s = trim(s)` and not `s = s.trim()`. `trim` would be the null-safe variant.

Comment: But that would kind of defeat the purpose, wouldn't it? `trim(s)` would have to check for `null` before it could call `s.trim()`, at which point `Strings.isNullOrEmpty(s')` is only half as useful. `StringUtils.isBlank(s)` seems like it does all that is desired here.

Comment: The bad side of `isBlank` is that it doesn't fix the input, so you end up validating against the whitespace-stripped string in the front end, but you continue processing with the whitespace-including string, which sounds odd.

Comment: Too bad Strings doesn't have the methods to do null-safe trimming either (e.g., StringUtils.trimToEmpty). If they did, it might show that they actually thought about usage a bit.

Answer (score 3):

`StringUtils.isBlank(str)` is very much different than `Strings.isNullOrEmpty(String string)`

> the first code sample will only check if the string is empty or not, it will include white spaces as well and return `true`

```
StringUtils.isBlank(null)      = true 
StringUtils.isBlank("")         = true 
StringUtils.isBlank(" ")        = true 
StringUtils.isBlank("bob")      = false
StringUtils.isBlank("  bob  ")  = false
```

> where as `Strings.isNullOrEmpty(String string)` Returns `true` if the given string is null or is the empty string

Answer (score 0):

`isBlank` is incredibly overrated. UI code that reads user text straight out of input fields can trim whitespace once and for all, and then you can stop worrying about it.

Comment: How is `isBlank` overrated?

Comment: Because UI code that reads user text straight out of input fields can trim whitespace once and for all, and then you can stop worrying about it.

Comment: What if you're writing code for non-web apps, like tools to import data from a flat file (someone generates a file from code w/a bug and you get a data field like "        " <-- tabs and spaces in there).  I'm just pointing out that not all code is pre-sanitized for you, and `isBlank` is great for those use cases.

Comment: @benson But is it really? Why would you want to trim the space out of " " so as to detect that it's empty, but preserve the space in " dog  "? Assuming you can conjure up a reason, how *often* is that what you want?  I maintain that `isBlank` is the most overused library method in history. :-)

Comment: @KevinBourrillion I suppose you will want is as often as you are dealing with legacy code that depends on that kind of checking, and you are trying to make that code easier to read.

Comment: Everytime I check for something about methods that do not exist in Guava, @KevinBourrillion seems to have an answer like "nobody needs this" or "it should not be this way". People are not always working in a perfect world, and may need to protect their data against crap. You know, when you're dealing with a business service that is used by dozens of beginners? or dealing with a batch that processes a flat file coming out of 50 year old IBM mainframe programer who was padding his zones with spaces before you were born, and doesn't give a f about Java ? that's real life dude, `isBlank` is useful

Comment: @MichaelakoTecourt In most of those cases we have *still* not found `isBlank` to be the best way to handle it. Sure, you may sometimes want it, but that in itself doesn't obligate Guava to be the thing that provides it for you.

Comment: @KevinBourrillion the reality is that most programmers now just write `Strings.nullToEmpty(str).trim().isEmpty()` because you know programmers are lazy & guava is still cool

Comment: As @MichaelTécourt remarks, you can be working on a backend API where you have to validate input from any number of third party integrators.  Even if you have a "front end", there can be multiple implementations and better to stop unwanted input right at the ingress.  In this age of cheap and rapid horizontal scaling, the cost is likely negligible.  Lastly, it's much nicer to read a single method call that does the obviously wanted thing.  I came to this SO post precisely because I inherited a bug caused by NOT having this.

Answer (score -5):

Guava is more or less targeted towards being a 'next generation' replacement of Apache Commons.  There really isn't much practical difference between using isBlank() vs isNullOrEmpty() beyond using one or the other consistently.

Comment: So what about the white space check that is the essence of this question?